# How elevate priviledge only to access windows registry

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, registry

I have a Visual Studio Forms application and I'm trying to implement a drag-n-drop operation from Windows Explorer into a button (or even a listbox).

But, due to some registry operations I have to perform within the code (in LOCAL_MACHINE key), I run my application ALWAYS as Administrator and it seems to invalidate any Drag-N-Drop operation from Windows Explorer into my application (I guess Windows Explorer never runs as Admin and that´s the main problem).

So, I´m actually between two paths:

1- If I put the application to run as Admin (elevated priviledges), I have no drag-n-drop from Windows Explorer but all accesses into Registry runs 100%.

2- If I put the application to run in low priviledge (no Admin), I have drag-n-drop (only to listbox, not into button) but the necessary operations into Windows Registry thrown an exception and cannot be performed.

I tried the following steps but I´m having exception in all modes if running the app in lower priviledges:

```
 Dim rkey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(MyKey, True)

    Dim rkey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(MyKey, True,
 Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.FullControl)

    Dim rkey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(MyKey, True, 
Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.TakeOwnership)
```

Is there any way to elevate the authorization ONLY DURING THE ACCESS INTO  WINDOWS REGISTRY? I´m using Visual Studio 2013 and coding in VB.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Kind regards.

Comment: There are several alternatives.  1) instead of accessing the registry, write out a `.reg` file and then start RegEdit elevated.    2) Run a copy of yourself elevated with a commandline switch. process the switch in Sub Main and exit.  If there is no switch, do a normal start.  The UAC will refer to the app running which is not aloarming.  3) Write a Console app to do the reg work.  For any of these to work on a 64bit OS, your app would have to be a 64bit process. Otherwise a 32bit process will start and the registry redirect will prevent the desired reg changes.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, but all the recommended actions are not acceptable in my application. It runs in XP, Vista, WIn7, Win 8/8.1 in 32/64 bits mode (we have more than 1500 users). The access into Registry may be performed in a secure mode, since the info is related to software registration dates. Anyway, I have an option to open a new application with a little windows just to receive the dragged info (like some download-applications do). It´s not the best solution, but in this case I have no skeleton changes into the main app. Thank you for your answer and attention. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change privileges to a running process. But you can start new process with elevated privileges and there do what you need to do.

You should create a small console app with code that needs elevated privileges and run this app by starting a process with elevated privileges.

It is a security thing - you don't want your app to run as Admin all the time.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I guess it´s not the desirable thing, since this console app should check Registry values and get important values to allow the main application continue (or not) running. I see that the OpenSubKey function can be parametrized with "PermissionCheck" and "AccessControl", but all combinations are failing here. Thanks for your answer and attention Martin.